# Check database size in previous day

Tags: mysql, database-size

I want to ask how do I get database size in previous day (example: Today is January 31st, and I want to get database size in January 22nd). 
Note: I do not have regular backups.

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, table_rows, data_length, index_length, 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024),2) "Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'my_own_schema'
```

But I only have the size of current time.

Thank you for any helps!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ask how do I get database size in previous day (example: Today is January 31st, and I want to get database size in January 22nd). Note: I do not have regular backups.

That's impossible. You could easily script a daemon (with something like `du`) that recorded that. Or you could use something an [lvm snapshot](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html) or XFS to get that information, if you were using a stack like that. But MySQL doesn't just record how big the database was at an arbitrary time.